# Multiple Feature Sets of different Size for Classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, classification, data-science

I have multiple different feature sets. These features are stored in dataframes. The Problem is, that they differ in size.
My first featureset is a 512 long sized vector of float.
The second featureset are 12 floats.
And so on.

I would like to use different classifiers on all of this feature sets. I think that I cant put all the features into on single vector because the performance will break because the cure of dimensionality and the missing influence of the small vectors.

So I had an idea:
Training multiple classificators on each featureset use these results as a new featureset for a final classificator.

Are there any standard ways of handling such problems?

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right that all your feature sets describe the same output then it makes most sense to actually predict based on all features. I would go with your first suggestion:

- merging all features in a single vector, although long one, shouldn't be a problem for classifier like SVM - it's intended to work OK with **many** features.

Your other idea:

- training a separate classifier for each feature set sound like adding additional complexity. Firs, you have one more abstraction to worry about. And second, the small/initial classifiers may not be that good if the have a limited amount of data small set of features (e.g. compared to a single SVM).

tl;dr: I would merge all features (if the different sets describe the same observations/variables, of course) and use them with an SVM.

Comment: Yes, i forgot it to say, that the datasets are so designed, the feature i in set1 has the same class as feature i in set2 .... so i will try it! thank you!